# Campaign Code inside email

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to use the campaign code I type in the campaign set up as an URL parameter. Is there a way for me to get to the value I type there and include it as a personalization string?

How about getting to that field for my data files back to my data warehouse. I would think any value I'm asked to fill out in the UI, I would be able to get to somehow.

Comment: Have you tried AMPScript?

Comment: I haven't tried ampscript. I think my main issue is, I can't find any documentation that let's me know a field name I can use to let me get to the data I want.

Comment: I can probably help if you can beef up your question with more detail and maybe some screenshots. I'm not fully following you.

Comment: In the Campaign Area of MC you can Set up a Campaign Name and a Campaign Code. I want to be able to reference the Campaign Code in the URLs of my Campaign. I may just need to use the additional attributes when I set up an email.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're referring to a Marketing Cloud Campaign, rather than a Sales Cloud Campaign?

There's no "straightforward" way to access the Campaign Code as a personalisation string. Here are two potential solutions. The first uses the tried-and-tested Web Analytics Connector, but is a bit manual. The second works automagically using the SFMC Campaigns API, but is a bit complex and hacky.

**Web Analytics Connector**

A less technical, but more manual solution would be just to make use of the [Web Analytics Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5) feature in Marketing Cloud in combination with the AdditionalInfo feature or an Additional Email Attribute. AdditionalInfo and AdditionalEmailAttributes appear on the Properties Tab of your email in Content Builder for users to enter the Campaign Code manually when they compose/send the email. You'll need a Support case asking for the following:

1. If you don't have WAC enabled, 'Please enable the Web Analytics Connector for this Business Unit (MID:nnnnnn)'.
2. If you want to enable an Additional Email Attribute (you can have up to five of these enabled) - 'Please enable one AdditionalEmailAttribute using the label "CampaignCode" in the UI'.
3. If you want the CampaignCode added to all URLs in your emails automatically, 'Please add the following to our "email_xtralinkparams" brand tag - "code=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%"'. Note that if using AdditionalInfo field, rather than AdditionalEmailAttributes, ask for the tag to be set to 'code=%%AdditionalInfo_%%'.

If you're not wanting to automatically append code to all links in your emails, you can add it manually to specific links, so:

```
<a href="https://mysite.com/foo?code=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%" alias="Some CTA">Click Me</a>
```

**Campaigns API**

The relationship between assets and campaigns is only available through the UI and from the REST API, so you'd need to go retrieve it from the API to add to your links. Here's a somewhat roundabout solution I had to implement a while back.

Create a new Code Snippet Content Block:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");
    // API Credentials
    var creds = {
        "rest":"https://<<replaced>>.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/",
        "authEndpoint": "<<replaced>>.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v1/requestToken",
        "clientId": "<<replaced>>",
        "clientSecret": "<<replaced>>"
    };

    var token, emailCampaign;

    if (Attribute.GetValue('_messagecontext') == 'SEND'){
        // Get Auth Token
        token = getToken();

        if (token) {
            emailCampaign = getEmailCampaign();
            if (emailCampaign.CampaignCode) {
                Write(emailCampaign.CampaignCode);
            }
        } else {
            //log("error", "Error logging send. No auth token available to access the REST API.");
        }
    }//if (Attribute.GetValue('_messagecontext') == 'SEND')


    function getEmailCampaign() {
        // Formulate REST query by Email Legacy ID
        var eid = Attribute.GetValue('_emailid');
        var endpoint = creds.rest + "asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1&$pagesize=50&$filter=data.email.legacy.legacyId%20eq%20";
        endpoint += eid;

        var campaign = {};
        var response;
        var status = [0];

        try {
            var content = Platform.Function.HTTPGet(endpoint, false, 0, ['Authorization'], ['Bearer ' + token], status);
            response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(content);

            if (response.items && response.items[0].data.campaigns) {
                var camp = {
                    "CampaignID":response.items[0].data.campaigns.campaigns[0].campaignId,
                    "LegacyEmailID":eid,
                    "EmailID":response.items[0].id,
                    "CampaignCode": null
                };

                // With the Campaign ID we can now get details of the campaign, including the Campaign ID
                endpoint = creds.rest + "hub/v1/campaigns/";
                endpoint += camp.CampaignID;

                content = Platform.Function.HTTPGet(endpoint, false, 0, ['Authorization'], ['Bearer ' + token], status);
                response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(content);

                camp.CampaignCode = response.campaignCode;

                return camp;
            } else {
                // Not a Content Builder Email - Get all Campaigns looping to search Campaign Assets for this email
                endpoint = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns?$pageSize=50&$page=";
                var page = 1;
                var eol = false;

                do {
                    content = Platform.Function.HTTPGet(endpoint + page, false, 0, ['Authorization'], ['Bearer ' + token], status);
                    response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(content);

                    if (response.items) {
                        if (response.items.length < 50) {
                            eol = true;
                        }

                        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
                            var assetURL = creds.rest + "hub/v1/campaigns/" + response.items[i].id + "/assets?$pageSize=50";
                            var d = Platform.Function.HTTPGet(assetURL, false, 0, ['Authorization'], ['Bearer ' + token], status);
                            var resp = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(d);

                            for (var a = 0; a < resp.items.length; a++) {
                                if (resp.items[a].type == "EMAIL" && resp.items[a].itemID == eid){
                                    return {
                                        "JobID": jid,
                                        "ListID": lid,
                                        "CampaignID": response.items[i].id,
                                        "LegacyEmailID": eid,
                                        "EmailID": eid,
                                        "CampaignCode": response.items[i].campaignCode
                                    };
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    page++;
                } while (eol == false);

            }
        } catch (err) {
            //Handle Error
        }

        return null;
    }


    function getToken() {
        var payload = Stringify({
            "clientId": creds.clientId,
            "clientSecret": creds.clientSecret
        });
        var content = [0];
        var accessToken;

        try {
            var statusCode = Platform.Function.HTTPPost(creds.authEndpoint, 'application/json', payload, null, null, content);
            accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(content[0]).accessToken;
            return accessToken;
        } catch (err) {
            //Handle Error
        }
    }
</script>
```

**NOTE:** You can shorten this code somewhat, if you only use ContentBuilder based emails.

Then use this line of AMPScript providing the Id of the Code Snippet above to set a variable to use in your URLs. You'd typically embed this in your email templates or the account header:

```
<!--
%%[
SET @Code = TreatAsContentArea('CA',ContentBlockById('1767'))
]%%
-->
```

The actual scripted content block that calls the API is only used once with the first subscriber to be sent the email - this is the behaviour of the [TreatAsContentArea()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontentarea.htm) function.

Finally, output the content of the Campaign Code in URLs, so:

```
%%=v(@Code)=%%
```

If you just need to get the relationship between Emails and Campaigns for your data warehouse and don't really need to use the Campaign Code in URLs, you can look at pulling back this data from the Campaigns and Assets APIs referenced in the code above.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the Marketing Cloud Campaign. I fear your solution may be out of reach for me. Thank you for taking the time to respond. Do you think I could declare the campaign code value in AmpScript and append it that way?   I could make a snippet of this code to include in every email I send and I would just need to add the campaign code value to it. Or as I responded to another answer add it as an additional attribute.

Comment: Yes. Sure. The most user friendly way is to ask for Support to enable the Web Analytics Connector (if it's not already enabled) and ask for an AdditionalEmailAttribute to be provisioned with the label "CampaignCode". This'll provide an input box on the Properties tab of your email in ContentBuilder. I'll update the answer to provide a little info.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to set a something to use as a URL parameter would be through "Personalization" %%something%% (including this as part of the query string appended to a link). This would just bring in a Field Name that you were using in your sending source. You could go one further and do a lookuprows ampscript function if you wanted to do it situationally. If you have the information in your send source this information will be readily available and able to be configured. This could be done a lot of different ways but Personalization would be the easiest.

Comment: The problem is I can't use the field in the campaign area as a personalization. I'd then have to add that field to a data extension and have it read from there.